# Error on executing sencha command (sencha touch2)

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I get this error:

```
sencha generate app GS ../GS
/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3/sencha: line 2: which: command not found
/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3/sencha: line 2: dirname: command not found
/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3/sencha: line 3: /bin/node: No such file or directory
```

I have the same error if I just execute sencha.. Any help please?

Comment: You're using an old version of Sencha's command line tools. The latest is Sencha Cmd v3

Answer (score 1):

Use latest Sencha Cmd. Once downloaded it, Install it in the bin folder of Sencha SDK Tools.
Use this link to download the latest version of Sencha Cmd http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download

Then type Sencha, it will show the version of Sencha cmd installed.